# PHP Spreadsheet HTML won't display chart

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to display a chart created in PHP spreadsheet in HTML. It is successful if I save to xlsx.

I'm using the chart creation code straight from the samples on github.
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/templates/chartSpreadsheet.php

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Html_Bootstrap($spreadsheet);
$writer->setEmbedImages(true);
$writer->writeAllSheets();
$html_writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
echo $html_writer->generateHTMLAll(); //shows table but no chart
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
$writer->save('test.xlsx'); //saves file with chart
```

Update:
I have tracked down the problem to line 738 of PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Html.php
failing to render. I'm assuming the `Settings::getRenderer()` is returning null.

Comment: Please bemore specific, what kind or response or error do you get, what have you already tried, etc.

Comment: There is no error. It displays the table data in html but no chart present on page. The chart is present however in the .xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the renderer:

```php
Settings::setChartRenderer(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Renderer\JpGraph::class);
```

See the sample for a complete example :
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Chart/32_Chart_read_write_HTML.php

Comment: 2 things, First, in order for the code to attempt the render I have to set the cell value that is the starting cell of the chart to something. `$sheet->setCellValue('D1', ' ');`
Second, I am now getting this response after setting the renderer.
`Uncaught Error: Class 'JpGraph\JpGraph' not found in /opt/web/common/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Chart/Renderer/JpGraph.php:65` the file is there

Comment: My apologies, I guess I need to download the JpGraph source code. Are the other renderers  compatible with html writer and open source? I would like to use for my company without getting a license.